# PyMongo Aggregation for Query Filters?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

So I'm finding questions similar but not quite answering what I'm looking for.  If this is a duplicate; feel free to point me to the appropriate place.

I have a collection which is a "source of truth" for some pretty large documents.  I would like to do some pre-filtering using the query engine before I get to my primary analytics.

Query 1:

Retrieve only documents where document.financials.entrycount $gte 4. So basically in a document I have a subdocument for financials. I want to use this as a filter. I only want to return documents where the number of entries there is greater than 4.

Query 2:

Be able to do math and compare that to a number for retrieval.

For example:

```
(totalAssets + totalCash) / (totalDebt + totalLiabilities) < .5
```

where those numbers are in a sub document.

Finally be able to combine that together.

Below is an example document projected down to only include quarterly financials.

```
{
  "symbol": "AAWW",
  "quarterly_financials": {
    "2017-09-30": {
      "cashChange": -106467000,
      "cashFlow": 82299000,
      "costOfRevenue": 439135000,
      "currentAssets": 449776000,
      "currentCash": 176280000,
      "currentDebt": 196509000,
      "grossProfit": 96613000,
      "netIncome": -24162000,
      "operatingExpense": 43690000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": 378000,
      "operatingIncome": 52923000,
      "operatingRevenue": 535748000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": None,
      "shareholderEquity": 1575169000,
      "totalAssets": 4687302000,
      "totalCash": 175926000,
      "totalDebt": 2105344000,
      "totalLiabilities": None,
      "totalRevenue": 535748000
    },
    "2017-12-31": {
      "cashChange": 115584000,
      "cashFlow": 136613000,
      "costOfRevenue": 474565000,
      "currentAssets": 587586000,
      "currentCash": 291864000,
      "currentDebt": 218013000,
      "grossProfit": 153387000,
      "netIncome": 209448000,
      "operatingExpense": 46628000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": -95000,
      "operatingIncome": 106759000,
      "operatingRevenue": 627952000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": None,
      "shareholderEquity": 1789856000,
      "totalAssets": 4955462000,
      "totalCash": 294413000,
      "totalDebt": 2226999000,
      "totalLiabilities": None,
      "totalRevenue": 627952000
    },
    "2018-03-31": {
      "cashChange": -161460000,
      "cashFlow": 69125000,
      "costOfRevenue": 498924000,
      "currentAssets": 433193000,
      "currentCash": 130404000,
      "currentDebt": 223308000,
      "grossProfit": 91090000,
      "netIncome": 9612000,
      "operatingExpense": 50521000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": None,
      "operatingIncome": 40569000,
      "operatingRevenue": 590014000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": None,
      "shareholderEquity": 1792299000,
      "totalAssets": 5016832000,
      "totalCash": 136421000,
      "totalDebt": 2270870000,
      "totalLiabilities": None,
      "totalRevenue": 590014000
    },
    "2018-06-30": {
      "cashChange": 97525000,
      "cashFlow": 106786000,
      "costOfRevenue": 548491000,
      "currentAssets": 565191000,
      "currentCash": 227929000,
      "currentDebt": 245322000,
      "grossProfit": 117654000,
      "netIncome": -21150000,
      "operatingExpense": 47334000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": None,
      "operatingIncome": 70320000,
      "operatingRevenue": 664531000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": None,
      "shareholderEquity": 1776073000,
      "totalAssets": 5348343000,
      "totalCash": 234280000,
      "totalDebt": 2501488000,
      "totalLiabilities": None,
      "totalRevenue": 666145000
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you have here is frankly with the document structure. Bottom line is that "sub-documents" named "by key" is not a good thing for any form of database to deal with in general, and this includes MongoDB.

Whilst it may be more efficient to "lookup by key" when working in client side code with a singular document, MongoDB works better with an "array" or "collection" like structure for such natural "lists" like this.

### Aggregation Expressions

The working alternative is to use an aggregation operator such as [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in order to "coerce" this form into a "natural list" for processing so you can filter by the number of entries in that list:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$gte": [
        { "$size": { "$objectToArray": "$quarterly_financials" } },
        4
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Note that this is using [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) from MongoDB 3.6 and above. If you don't have that supporting version but still have [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) from a later MongoDB 3.4 release ( even though the docs say 3.6 it was actually in those later releases ) then you could use something like [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) in place of a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) or regular `find()` for that matter.

The same goes for the additional calculated expression. Bottom line is that you still need the "array conversion" in order to actually process and *traverse* those *"list elements"*. So in the case where only those sub-entries which meet the condition add up to the **four** required, then you would be altering with a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) condition on the array elements:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [
          { "$size": { 
            "$filter": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$quarterly_financials" },
              "cond": {
                "$lt": [
                  { "$divide": [
                    { "$add": [ "$$this.v.totalAssets", "$$this.v.totalCash" ] },
                    { "$add": [ 
                      "$$this.v.totalDebt",
                      { "$ifNull": [ "$$this.v.totalLiabilities", 0 ] }
                    ]}
                  ]},
                  .5
                ]
              }
            }
          }},
          4
        ]
      }
  }}
])
```

So after *"coercing to an array"* then each list item is examined with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to determine where the mathematical expression using operators like [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) and [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) meet the logical condition with the [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) before that remaining filtered array is considered for it's *"length"* using the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator.

Also note that [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) essentially transforms each sub-document into a list with this form:

```
   {
        "k" : "2018-06-30",
        "v" : {
            "cashChange" : 97525000,
            "cashFlow" : 106786000,
            "costOfRevenue" : 548491000,
            "currentAssets" : 565191000,
            "currentCash" : 227929000,
            "currentDebt" : 245322000,
            "grossProfit" : 117654000,
            "netIncome" : -21150000,
            "operatingExpense" : 47334000,
            "operatingGainsLosses" : null,
            "operatingIncome" : 70320000,
            "operatingRevenue" : 664531000,
            "researchAndDevelopment" : null,
            "shareholderEquity" : 1776073000,
            "totalAssets" : 5348343000,
            "totalCash" : 234280000,
            "totalDebt" : 2501488000,
            "totalLiabilities" : null,
            "totalRevenue" : 666145000
        }
    }
```

Which means everything you are looking for is under the `"v"` property ( or *"value"* ) of each document in the newly transformed "list". The `"k"` property is of course the "key" which you named under with the "sub-document" form.

Also [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) is a requirement for dealing with the `null` ( or `None` for Python ) values present for properties, or indeed *"missing"* properties where appropriate.

### JavaScript Evaluation

Not really recommended, but the other alternate where your MongoDB does not support the newer operators such as [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) is to use JavaScript evaluation on the server such as with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) or [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) which process such logic.

The same principles apply in that you must "coerce" into an array form first. ( forgiving the "shell form" shorthand example here. Just a string in all other languages ):

```
collection.find(function() {
  var quarter = this.quarterly_financials;
  return Object.keys(quarter).filter( k => 
    ( 
      ( quarter[k].totalAssets + quarter[k].totalCash ) /
      ( quarter[k].totalDebt + ( quarter[k].totalLiabilites || 0 ) )
    ) < .5
  ).length >= 4
})
```

Whilst *"less noisy"* it's not really optimal as the *"cost"* for evaluating JavaScript expressions on the server is considerably higher than the natural language aggregation expression. It also a possibility that certain environments and server configurations actually don't permit you to use such JavaScript expressions at all.

Note also if you really want "aggregation" at a later stage of analysis, then you need to factor that logic into a `mapReduce` since it is not possible to use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) query expressions within an aggregation pipeline.

### Alternate Structure

Finally, since everything relies on *"making a list"* from your "named keys" then the better approach is generally to structure your data that way in the first place ( excusing the [extended JSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) ):

```
{
  "symbol": "AAWW",
  "quarterly_financials": [
    { 
      "tranDate": { "$date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00Z"},
      "cashChange": -106467000,
      "cashFlow": 82299000,
      "costOfRevenue": 439135000,
      "currentAssets": 449776000,
      "currentCash": 176280000,
      "currentDebt": 196509000,
      "grossProfit": 96613000,
      "netIncome": -24162000,
      "operatingExpense": 43690000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": 378000,
      "operatingIncome": 52923000,
      "operatingRevenue": 535748000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 1575169000,
      "totalAssets": 4687302000,
      "totalCash": 175926000,
      "totalDebt": 2105344000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "totalRevenue": 535748000
    },
    {
      "tranDate": { "$date": "2017-12-31T00:00:00Z" },
      "cashChange": 115584000,
      "cashFlow": 136613000,
      "costOfRevenue": 474565000,
      "currentAssets": 587586000,
      "currentCash": 291864000,
      "currentDebt": 218013000,
      "grossProfit": 153387000,
      "netIncome": 209448000,
      "operatingExpense": 46628000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": -95000,
      "operatingIncome": 106759000,
      "operatingRevenue": 627952000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 1789856000,
      "totalAssets": 4955462000,
      "totalCash": 294413000,
      "totalDebt": 2226999000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "totalRevenue": 627952000
    },
    { 
      "tranDate": { "$date": "2018-03-31T00:00:00Z" },
      "cashChange": -161460000,
      "cashFlow": 69125000,
      "costOfRevenue": 498924000,
      "currentAssets": 433193000,
      "currentCash": 130404000,
      "currentDebt": 223308000,
      "grossProfit": 91090000,
      "netIncome": 9612000,
      "operatingExpense": 50521000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": null,
      "operatingIncome": 40569000,
      "operatingRevenue": 590014000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 1792299000,
      "totalAssets": 5016832000,
      "totalCash": 136421000,
      "totalDebt": 2270870000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "totalRevenue": 590014000
    },
    { 
      "tranDate": { "$date": "2018-06-30T00:00:00Z" },
      "cashChange": 97525000,
      "cashFlow": 106786000,
      "costOfRevenue": 548491000,
      "currentAssets": 565191000,
      "currentCash": 227929000,
      "currentDebt": 245322000,
      "grossProfit": 117654000,
      "netIncome": -21150000,
      "operatingExpense": 47334000,
      "operatingGainsLosses": null,
      "operatingIncome": 70320000,
      "operatingRevenue": 664531000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 1776073000,
      "totalAssets": 5348343000,
      "totalCash": 234280000,
      "totalDebt": 2501488000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "totalRevenue": 666145000
    }
  ]
}
```

Since it's already a "list", you just skip the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) parts ( or similar with JavaScript ):

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$gte": [
        { "$size": { 
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$quarterly_financials",
            "cond": {
              "$lt": [
                { "$divide": [
                  { "$add": [ "$$this.totalAssets", "$$this.totalCash" ] },
                  { "$add": [ 
                    "$$this.totalDebt",
                    { "$ifNull": [ "$$this.totalLiabilities", 0 ] }
                  ]}
                ]},
                .5
              ]
            }
          }
        }},
        4
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

There is also a lot more advantages into using this sort of structure instead, and most of those would typically even avoid evaluated expressions entirely and be able to use natural query expressions. In fact if your conditions here were not in fact that that **four** need be dependent on such a a *"filtered"* condition, then this is just a natural query if you already *"pre-calculate"* the math expressions in every list entry beforehand at time of storage.

So *"structure"* is always something you really should consider for best query performance, since *"evaluating"* in any form causes collection scans and is very costly.

Therefore "use lists" where things are lists, and where calculations are "static" then do them beforehand and store them, rather than computing at run time.